# How to force datatype boolean in mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

`CREATE VIEW as SELECT ... FROM mytable`

This creates a view with a column `int unsiged`.

But what I want is a `boolean` or `tinyint` column datatype in my view.

Is that possible, because neither `CAST()` nor `CONVERT()` seem to support casting to a `boolean` type.

If I create a normal table, the following results in a `tinyint(1)`:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  Id        int(10)      unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  myflag    boolean      default false,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
```

Can't I achieve the same in a view, means **explicit setting a columns type to `tinyint`(1)**?

Comment: MySQL doesn't really have a boolean type.

Comment: Of course 1 = true and 0 = false, but I'm rather looking into how to enforce the **datatype** of the column inside the view, not the logic.

Comment: Can't cast to a tinyint either, afaicr

Comment: Please include the exact view definition and the insert/update that produces the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL views do return TINYINT, but only if you query a column of that type. All other integer expressions return BIGINT.

I ran `mysql --column-type-info` to get debugging info on the results.

```
mysql> create table t ( b bool );

mysql> create or replace view v as select b from t;

mysql> select b from v;
Field   1:  `b`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `test2`
Table:      `v`
Org_table:  `v`
Type:       TINY
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 0
Decimals:   0
Flags:      NUM 

mysql> select NOT b from v;
Field   1:  `NOT b`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 0
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY NUM 

mysql> create or replace view v (b) as select NOT b from t;

mysql> select b from v;
Field   1:  `b`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      `v`
Org_table:  `v`
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     1
Max_length: 0
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY NUM
```